# Is it possible to use java SE library in J2me?

Tags: java, java-me

is it possible for me to use java library such as

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

in my j2me project?

Comment: i tried, but can't . that's why i'm curious about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You can try to add the jars as third party libraries, but you may find conflicts. More important, when you finally deploy in the target system, you may find that these libraries do not work with that JVM.